# In bash, how to find files which there is "test" string in,Exclude binary files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, find

`find . -type f  |xargs grep string |awk -F":" '{print $1}' |uniq`

the command above,it get all files' name  which contain string "test". but the result includes
binary file.

The problem is how to exclude binary file.

thanks you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand properly, you want to get the name of all the files in the directory and its subdirectories that contain the string `string`, excluding binary files.

Reading `grep`'s friendly manual, I was able to catch this:

```
-I     Process a binary file as if it did not  contain  matching  data;
       this is equivalent to the --binary-files=without-match option.
```

Amazing!

Now how about I get rid of `find`. Is this possible with just `grep`? Oh, two lines below, still in the funky manual, I read this:

```
 -R, -r, --recursive
          Read all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively;  this  is
          equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

That seems great, doesn't it?

How about getting only the file name? Still in `grep`'s funny manual, I read:

```
   -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
          file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
          scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

Yay! I think we're done:

```
grep -IlR 'string' .
```

**Remarks.**

- I also tried to find `make me a sandwich` in the manual, but my version of `grep` doesn't seem to support it. YMMV.
- The manual is located at `man grep`.
- As William Pursell rightly comments, the `-R` and `-I` switches are not available in all implementations of `grep`. If your `grep` possesses the `make me a sandwich` option, it will very likely support the `-R` and `-I` switches. YMMV.

Comment: Note that `-I` and `-R` are non-standard options that are not available in all implementations of `grep`.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf, thank you!That's very helpful. And it's so nice of your answer, giving every details.
BTW, what dose "make me a sandwich" mean ? I googled out "YMMV"。but could not find "make me a sandwich". Sorry, English is not my mother language

Answer (score 0):

Version of Unix that I work with, does not support the command "grep -I/R".

I tried the command:

```
file `find ./` | grep text | cut -d: -f1 | xargs grep "test"
```